# Como faço para testar o tipo do usuário e mandar para views diferentes em generic views do DJANGO

Tags: python, django

Ola, estou com uma dúvida no Django. Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma. Meu modelo de usuário tem um campo "nivel", esse campo tem alguns niveis, entre eles "root", "seller" etc.. Porém, gostaria de saber como posso restringir algumas views somente para o "root", outras somente para o "seller", etc. Desconsiderando o admin do django, visto que tenho mais de dois niveis de acesso.

EX: Gostaria de permitir na minha view de criação do usuário que somente o usuário "seller" pode criar outro usuário. Como faço isso ? Já tentei pegar o objeto do usuário logado com o "request.user" no generic view, mas não funciona. Agradeço muito desde já. Se puderem mandar um pequeno trecho de código como exemplo. Valeu!

Segue a view generic:

```
class RegisterView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'new.html'
    form_class = UserAdminCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:login')
```

Gostaria de mandar para "new.html" somente se o usuário logado fosse do tipo "seller", caso não fosse, mandaria para "accounts:dashboard".

Meu modelo de usuário:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ADM = 0
    MAIN = 1
    SEL = 2
    AUT = 3
    USER = 5
    TYPES = (
        (ADM, 'root'),
        (MAIN, 'maintainer'),
        (SEL, 'seller'),
        (AUT, 'author'),
        (USER, 'user')
    )
    username = models.CharField(
            'Apelido / Usuário', max_length=30, unique=True, validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
            re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'),
            'Informa um nome de usuário válido. '
            'Este valor deve conter apenas letras, números '
            'e os caracteres: @/./+/-/_ .',
            'invalid'
            )
        ], help_text='Um nome curto que será usado para identificá-lo de forma única na plataforma'
    )
    name = models.CharField('Nome',max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True)
    nivel = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES, default=USER)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('Equipe', default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Ativo', default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('Data de Entrada', auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin


class SellerLoginRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.nivel == User.SEL:
            return redirect('accounts:dashboard')
        return super(SellerLoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

E na view:

```
class RegisterView(LoginRequiredMixin, SellerLoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'new.html'
    form_class = UserAdminCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:login')
```

Comment: Cara, tudo certo. Perfeito! muito boa a solução. Só mais uma coisa, quando tento acessar como AnonymousUser retorna um erro, como posso tratar nesse método SellerLoginRequiredMixin se ele nao é AnonymousUser. Desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu editei o código para atender a requisição do AnonymousUser

Comment: Valeu, tudo certo! obrigado mesmo, e parabéns pelo conhecimento :)

Answer (score 2):

Por que você não cria grupos em vez de criar um model User personalizado? Aí trata tudo com as permissões fornecidas ao grupo. E pra não ter chance de você esquecer de cadastrar um grupo ou permissão na implantação do site você pode carregar dados no syncdb usando fixtures.
[Documentação de fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/.../1.11/howto/initial-data/)

E pra verificar as permissões você usa o método has_perm() da classe User
[Documentação de has_perm()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm)